# What is Batman's "prep time"?

Tags: dc, batman

In many discussions about Batman and his abilities, *prep time* is always mentioned and emphasized.

What is this "prep time"?

Has it already been called as such in-universe?

**What are some examples of this ability in use?** (Comics, animation, etc. .)

Comment: Yes, a simple Google search would answer the first question, but I think that's a good question to have here and the question felt incomplete with only the last two questions.

Comment: The final question, as is seems quite subjective, "best examples" by what measure? Which I though were the coolest? Which Billybob thought was the coolest? Or what?

Comment: @Edlothiad edited to some. The best was to the example, I wanted a example which exposed plenty of Batman's ability and thought process. But I accept your point.

Comment: You seem to be referring to the [Crazy Prepared/Batman](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/CrazyPrepared/Batman) trope (**Standard TVTropes Warning**). That seems to have various details there.

Comment: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/batman-286/batman-vs-the-justice-league-endgame-1685595/ - This is a pretty solid example of Batman fighting against known enemies with sufficient time to prepare

Comment: Remember the time Batman fought a monkey? http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_kxF371gMSro/R1CyvR4Sf6I/AAAAAAAAAxQ/aGIvltD44Ws/s1600-R/scan0073.jpg

Comment: @Valorum That looks more like some kind of ape (I *think* it's supposed to be a gorilla). But yes, this dies prove that Batman can do anything if he prepares!

Comment: @Adamant - It's not related, I just wanted to share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prep time - time to prepare**

The point is that Batman can always overcome anything as long as he has time to analyze the threat and prepare for it accordingly. Examples can be found in comics such as:

- The Return of the Dark Knight (Elseworlds) - Batman defeats Superman because he had years to acquire enough Kryptonite and prepare a battle plan.
- Endgame (New 52) - Batman defeats jokerized Justice League because he spent millions on developing a battle suit capable of defeating each of the League members.
- Tower of Babel - This story revolves around SB stealing Batman's plans for defeating members of the League.

To my knowledge, nobody called it "prep time" explicitly in the comics, but it probably is recognized by Batman's foes. Bane genuinely surprised Batman in the Knightfall and Joker in Death of the Family tends to plan against Batman's plans and gadgets (and gadgets are an embodiment of prep time).